# Where is the return value from a recursive call to a function stored to be accessed by the calling function?

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, callstack

where in stack /registers is it stored and how is it accessed by the calling function.
I am not able to understand that if frame is popped out of the stack when return statement is encountered then where does the returned value exist to be accessed in calling function and how does the function access it.
Language : C

Comment: Depends. Could be a register, but could also be the stack (for bigger structs for example).

Comment: Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions. There is literally no difference at all.

Comment: Depends on the calling convention (more broadly ABI) of your platform and on the type of the return value. E.g., x86-64 SysV ABI platforms return single integers through the %rax register, two integer-structs through {%rax, %rdx}, and larger structs through memory stack-allocated by the caller through a hidden pointer passed as the first param (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

Comment: The C spec doesn't... specify this as it is platform-dependent.

Comment: Most commonly in modern systems, a return value of modest size, such as an `int`, `double`, or very small structure, is placed in a particular processor register. For return values of larger sizes, such as a structure of dozens of bytes or more, the caller is required to pass a “hidden” parameter (present in assembly language but not visible in the C source code) that contains the address of space where the called function writes the return value.

Comment: This is much easier to understand through examples than through abstract explanations.  Take an example of a function that does this, compile it, and study the assembly language output by the compiler.  You can also single-step the assembly code with a debugger.

Comment: If function A calls function B, where is the return value from function B stored? If B's frame is popped off the stack when the return statement in B is encountered, then where does the returned value exist in the calling function and how does the function access it?